What does '...are quite well down the politeness scale...' mean?

Closely related to desire/willingness is prospective intentional
future, as in Are/Aren’t you going to tidy your room? These express
doubt as to whether you intend to do what you should do, and for this
reason are quite well down the politeness scale.

Does the 'down' have the sense of 'below', hence the negative meaning of 'not polite'?

I question the writer's invention of prospective intentional future. It sounds like a small category that you won't run into often enough to need the category.

near the bottom of the scale

Yes, down the scale has the sense of low.
Imagine a scale measuring degrees of politeness in which 10 is 'extremely polite' and 0 is 'rude'. The author suggests that asking someone "Aren't you going to [do something]?" is rather low on the scale - it implies that they obviously ought to have done that thing already.

well|far down (on) the _____ scale is a rather overused construction these days, often used as a mock-serious or as a snarky put-down as it admits creation of ad hoc  "scales"

Gas-station sushi is well down the fine-dining scale.
Her new novel is well down on the good-reads scale.

in addition to the usual scales:

the social scale,
the evolutionary scale,
the income scale,
the economic scale,
the age scale,
the educational scale

